# Why does discord return 403 on any request?

Tags: java, https, discord

I am trying to send https request to discord api form java, but discord is responding with 403. 
 My code is:

```
String query = "client_id=id" +
                    "&client_secret=secret" +
                    "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
                    "&code=" + code +
                    "&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("https://discordapi.tridentgames.eu/oauth2", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token").openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            output.writeBytes(query);
            output.close();

            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read())
                System.out.print((char) c);
            input.close();
```

It is running in pterodactyl's docker container. I tried to execute the same request from postman and it is ok, even I was unsuccesfull when I tried to recreate the 403 error from postman. I also tried to change the URL, but result is same even with only `https://discord.com`. I also tried to curl discord api from the docker container and it was ok. Also, the code is based on my older node.js code, that worked without any problems. 
 Does anyone know what's wrong with my request?

Comment: Did you write `"client_id=id" + "&client_secret=secret"`  to hide the credentials for SO, or is that in your actual query?

Comment: I just did it to hide the credentials. And btw, it should return 401 if the credentials are incorrect.

Comment: You should use an http library like okhttp

Comment: @Minn, what are its pros compared to the build-in https class?

Comment: Pros are active development, modern implementation, correct and full coverage of the standard, proper defaults, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Discord expects a User-Agent, which Java doesn't send by default.

Add:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java");
```

and it should work.

My code if needed:

```
URL url = new URL("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token");
URLConnection httpConn = url.openConnection();
OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String json = "";

httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // do a POST
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
httpConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java");

// Convert the code into an id token
try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(
            "code=" + code +
            "&client_id=" + DISCORD_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID +
            "&client_secret=" + DISCORD_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET +
            "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
            "&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode(returnUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
    writer.flush();
    
    String line;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
    
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        json = json + line;
    }
}
finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```